# show a view on 2 viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm looking for a way to show a `UIView` "`InventoryView`" in 2 view controllers.

I'm working on an inventory system for my game that I trying to make but I need to be able to access it from my main view, where it will go to a `InventoryViewController` (in this ViewController is my InventoryView) but I also need to be able to access the `InventoryView` from my BattleViewController where it does not go to my `InventoryViewController` but where it print the `InventoryView` on my `BattleViewController` so I can access everything durning the battle.

Example:
(evrything is dragand drop, the UIView and the UIButtons)

### InventoryViewController

```
      class InventoryViewController: UIViewController {

          class InventoryView: UIView {
//here are some UIButtons and labels
}
}
```

---

### BattleViewController

```
class BattleViewController: UIViewController {
class InventoryView: UIView {
 //it should print the Inventory Screen on my BattleViewController
//here are the same properties as it shows in the InventoryViewController
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code please

Comment: i'm at work atm so that's not possible,
wil try to do it this midday

Comment: and there isen't much coding to put here..
Just need to know if its possible that i can use a UIView from 1 ViewController into another

Comment: What's the problem with it? Declare it in the viewcontroller's include and use it.

Comment: @ott , and how do i do that? :P
I'm kinda new to it, trying to make a small clicking battle game
but i just don't know how to add my InventoryView in my BattleViewController.

Comment: i added an Example, hope that might help :)

Comment: @Kristof.V best option would be to add that View in Window From Appdelegate file. Thats It...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great example to look at the way OOP programming works best.
Ask yourself the following questions:

- What is the purpose of the view?
- Are the interactions on the view homogenous across all the instances? (touch events, specific behavior, etc...)
- What is the minimum amount of information you need to make the view look the way you want?

Once you have those answers, you can approach the concept of reusability of views safely.

The way to go about it is to subclass UIView, create the necessary elements of your view, setup your constraints (still in the view, either in a nib or programmatically), and implement any behavior that will be consistent across views (For example if the view is a segmented control, every time you click a segment all the others go grey and the one you clicked go blue. Since that's the primary purpose of the segmented control, the code for it should belong to the segmented control).

Chances are you will find the docs very useful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/

Lastly write a setup method that takes all the information you need and sets up all your graphical elements accordingly. Remember, views should never own their data (they should be templates, the controller will provide the data).

I have no idea what you view looks like but I assume the inventory is represented as an object. Then something like could be a good start:

```
  class InventoryView: UIView {

    var inventory: Inventory? {
      didSet {
        if let newInventory = inventory { //in case we set it to nil
          setup(withInventory: newInventory)
        }
      }
    }

    private func setup(withInventory inventory: Inventory) {
      //do your setup here
    }
  }
```

Then in your controller you can call:

```
let inventoryView = InventoryView()
inventoryView.inventory = myPlayer.inventory
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a view in two places, at least not within the UI. Every view can be added to only one super view at a time.

If you need the same contents to be displayed twice, create a `UIViewController` class which's view contains the common UI, create two of those and add them to your UI.